# How to Modify an Existing iOS App to Support Split View

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an existing iOS app with a Navigation Controller (root view) that is set up as the initial view controller. In the storyboard, it has a Relationship "root view controller" to "my app". "My App" is a View Controller that has a Table View within the view.

I would like to make the initial view controller be a Split View Controller. When I drag a Split View Controller into my storyboard, it gives me a Split View Controller, a Navigation Controller, a View Controller, and a Table View Controller.

What I tried to do is connect my app into this model. First, I deleted the Table View Controller that came with the Split View Controller. Then I deleted my original Navigation Controller. Then I connected the new Navigation Controller to "my app" to create a Relationship "root view controller" to "my app". Finally, I made the Split View Controller be the initial view controller.

When I compiled and ran the app in the simulator, my app delegate (application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) runs, but nothing else (i.e. I end up with a black screen). What else do I need to do to connect my app to this model for it to operate as a Split View?

Comment: Did you remember to set a view controller as the Initial view controller?

Comment: @matt yes, the split view controller is set to initial view controller